# is it true that Islam Spread by the Sword? or Declared many War?

Tags: history, caliph

In the past Islam had big glory and had many region, could someone tell me why Islam had accomplished such a big glory and had so many region?

according to that, is it true Islam had Declared so many war so they had many Region?
Please answer with Reference and explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: This question isn't very clear or focussed, by the looks of it you're basically just asking for the entire history, referenced, of warfare in the Islamic world.  Without some focus (e.g. when exactly "in the past"?  how many is "so many" wars/regions?  and what even counts as "Islam" that can declare a war in the first place?) this is pretty much unanswerable with the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose that period into two parts

1. the period when the prophet was alive
2. the period after the death of prophet

**1- THE PERIOD WHEN PROPHET MOHAMMAD WAS ALIVE**

in this period for 13 years, the muslims suffered from quraish leader followers and they were hurting them

example of this action:

> Family of Yasser: Yasser Bin Ammar and his wife Summaya Bint Kheyat (
>   the first woman to martyr in islam)

Muslims was asking at that period from prophet to ask God to allow them to fight the non-believers and to protect themselves till the verses about jihad came and it was clear like stated in chapter 2 verse 190:

> Fight in the way of Allah against those who fight against you, but
>   begin not hostilities. Lo! Allah loveth not aggressors.

and stated in chapter 2 verse 217:

> They question thee (O Muhammad) with regard to warfare in the sacred
>   month. Say: Warfare therein is a great (transgression), but to turn
>   (men) from the way of Allah, and to disbelieve in Him and in the
>   Inviolable Place of Worship, and to expel His people thence, is a
>   greater with Allah; for persecution is worse than killing. And they
>   will not cease from fighting against you till they have made you
>   renegades from your religion, if they can. And whoso becometh a
>   renegade and dieth in his disbelief: such are they whose works have
>   fallen both in the world and the Hereafter. Such are rightful owners
>   of the Fire: they will abide therein.

and stated in chapter 22 verse 39:

> Sanction is given unto those who fight because they have been wronged;
>   and Allah is indeed Able to give them victory;

Muslims view that the Muslims fought only when attacked, or in the context of a wider war of self-defense ... and this was in the period when prophet Mohammad was alive, in my opinion

**2- THE PERIOD AFTER THE DEATH OF MOHAMMAD**

this period also can be decomposed into several steps:

***a- when Abu-Bakr was Khalifa***

in this period: battles was made against those they refused to give him the allegiance ( Wars of apostasy ), and in these battles, many many of people that was by hearting the Quran been killed more that 500!, these battles has no deal with what was stated in quran for the Jihad and battles verses.

***b- when Omar was Khalifa***

in this period: Muslims was initiating battles in the name of ( spreading the name of God), in other words, they call it as Islamic Conquests

***c- when Uthman was Khalifa***
in this period, Muslims was against each other and the FITNA started

***d- when Ali was Khalifa***
the FITNA continued, and many battles the muslims and their brothers was made and many was killed and the most famous events was: Battle of the Camel, and the death of Ammar ibn Yasir

**e- After death of Imam Ali:**

the government in islam converted from work towards God, to work towards the khalifa in my opinion

this period in my opinion, it was nothing related for saving the muslims or defending themselves, most of the battles was in the name of extending the Empire of Muslims represented by the Khalifa.

hope this will help you and if you need more information about something i didn't explain in details, go ahead and ask about it.

reference :

1. [List of expeditions of Muhammad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_expeditions_of_Muhammad)
2. [Ammar ibn Yasir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammar_ibn_Yasir)
3. [Muslim conquests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_conquests)
4. [Ridda Wars - wars of apostasy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridda_wars)
5. [Battle of the camel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Camel)